# How to exit or retry based on long running command result

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to monitor the output of `long_running_command` function(can't make changes to this), If the output contains `result='good'` then `print WOW` and return. However, until the `long_running_command` did not return `result='good'` keep trying until `MAX_TRY` is reached. **So far its all good.** However, if the command already returned `result='failed'` then there is no point of retrying, how can I error out(print `NAY`) without retrying ?

Below is sample program(Minimum working problem statement):

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_TRY=5


#Simulating a fake long running command that may return good or failed randomly with a small delay
long_running_command()
{

    wait_time=$(shuf -i 1-5 -n 1)
    sleep "$wait_time"

    if [ "$path" -eq 1 ];then
        echo "result='good'"
    elif [ "$path" -eq 0 ];then
        echo "result='failed'"
    else
        echo "This path should never hit"
    fi

}



# Some external conditions cannot be controlled by me, faking it
#0 means fail
#1 means pass
path=$(shuf -i 0-1 -n 1)



check_result() {
    while [ $MAX_TRY -le 10 ];do
    if long_running_command |grep -qE 'result.*good' ;then
        echo "$(date): WOW"
        return 0 
    fi
        echo "$(date): Retrying...so far the output does not have good in it or perhaps its failed already"
    MAX_TRY=$((MAX_TRY + 1))
         
    done
    echo "$(date): NAY"
}

check_result
```

TLDR, I need to exit from the retry loop if the command has returned failed or good.  Later, print `WOW or NAY based on the results.

Comment: Does it always output either `good` or `failed`?

Comment: it could be blank for a few seconds then it will turn to good or failed.

Comment: You're waiting for it to finish, not processing the output as it arrives.

Comment: yes, wait for it to finish(1-5 seconds), it could either return failed or good, if failed then no point of waiting or retrying.

Comment: If it always returns either good or failed, when would you retry?

Comment: for a first few retries, it return `blank` (no output), later it says good or failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the output in a variable. Then you can test whether it contains `result='good'` or `result='failed'`. If neither, you retry.

```
check_result() {
    while [ $MAX_TRY -le 10 ]
    do
        output=$(long_running_command | grep -E "result='(good|failed)'")
        case "$output" in
            *good*) 
                # Return success immediately
                echo "$(date): WOW"
                return 0
                ;;
            *failed*)
                # No point in retrying
                break
                ;;
        esac
        MAX_TRY=$((MAX_TRY + 1))
    done
    echo "$(date): NAY"
    return 1
}
```

Comment: thanks!, working nice when fit  with real code.